# Improvement in NextJS react code mandatory error banner before clicking button

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, next.js13

I have page with content having links and a button at end ‘I agree’. On clicking button, I made sure link is open at least one time by showing Error banner on page. Once link is clicked, the error banner won’t render next time. I implemented it with following code

```
function AgreeDocument): JSX.Element {
  const [showViewDocumentError, setShowViewDocumentError] = useState(false);
  const [viewedDocuments, setViewedDocuments] = useState(false);

  const isAgreementClicked = () => {
     setViewedDocuments(true);
     setShowViewDocumentError(false);
  }
   return ({showViewDocumentError && (<Box>Please open document </Box>)}<Content callback={() => {isAgreementClicked();}}/>);

}

function content({callback}): JSX.Element {
  return (<Box>Hello, please provide me the info on this <a href=“/helm.pdf” onClick={callback}>doc</a></Box><Box><Button type=“button”>I agree</Button></Box>);
}
```

How can I improve the above code so, if we add any other mandatory open link  in content, corresponding different Error banner to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the state of the second banner as true, when you close the first banner. So that the second banner is displayed.

```
const [firstBanner, setFirstBanner] = useState(true);    

const [secondBanner, setSecondBanner] = useState(false);        

function closeFirstBanner () => {
setFirstBanner(false);  // first banner is closed
setSecondBanner(true); // now second banner is shown
}
```